# How to open popup in jquery in this case?

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, popup

I tried to open a popup in a page and it worked very well, but now I am trying to open it in an "info" window of Google map marker and it doesn't work anymore. Here's my code:

In head :

```
  var chaine = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
  var reg=new RegExp("[ ,]+", "g");
  var mot= chaine.split(reg);

  // add each marker's location to the bounds
  bounds.extend(point);

  var html =  " Dernier statut : " + name + " <br><a href='#' data-popup-target='#example-popup2'>Cliquez-ici pour voir le profil de "+ mot[1] +"</a><br><img with=28 src=images/message.png><a href=# alt="+ mot[0] +"|"+ mot[1] +" class=chat_user>Clavarder</a> ";
```

In body :

```
<div id="example-popup2" class="popup">
  <div class="popup-body">
    <span class="popup-exit"></span>
    <div class="popup-content">
      <h2 class="popup-title">test</h2>
      <p>
        <div style="text-align:justify;">
          <div class="login"></div>
        </div>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="popup-overlay"></div>
```

I think the problem is with the `""` in `var html` :

```
<a href='#' data-popup-target='#example-popup2'>
```